# What will be regex for checking alphanumeric dot dash and underschore using preg_match?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am checking **username** entered by user

I'm trying to validate usernames in PHP using preg_match() but I can't seem to get it working the way I want it. I require preg_match() to:

- accept only letters , numbers and . - _

i.e. alphanumeric dot dash and underscore only, i tried regex from htaccess which is like this

```
([A-Za-z0-9.-_]+)
```

like this way but it doesnt seem to work, it giving false for simple alpha username.

```
$text = 'username';

if (preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9.-_]$/' , $text)) {
   echo 'true';   
} else {
   echo 'false';
}
```

How can i make it work ?

i am going to use it in function like this

```
//check if username is valid
function isValidUsername($str) {
    return preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9.-_]/', $str);
}
```

i tried answwer in [preg_match() and username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379813/preg-match-and-username) but still something is wrong in the regex.

---

**update**

I am using code given by **xdazz** inside function like this.

```
//check if username is valid
function isValidUsername($str) {
    if (preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9._-]+$/' , $str)) {
       return true;   
    } else {
       return false;
    }
}
```

and checking it like

```
$text = 'username._-546_546AAA';


if (isValidUsername($text) === true) {
echo 'good';
}
else{
echo 'bad';
}
```

Comment: if (preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9.-_]$/' , $text)) here a + or * is required.or else it will match a single character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the `+`(`+` for one or more, `*` for zero or more), or your regex only matches a string with one char.

```
if (preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9._-]+$/' , $text)) {
   echo 'true';   
} else {
   echo 'false';
}
```

Comment: thanks, this is working as expected, i tried escaping - like this \- but it didnt worked,.

Answer (score 2):

hyphen `-` has special meaning inside `[...]` that is used for range.

It should be in the beginning or in the last or escape it like `([A-Za-z0-9._-]+)` otherwise it will match all the character that is in between `.` and `_` in ASCII character set.

Read similar post [Including a hyphen in a regex character bracket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697202/including-a-hyphen-in-a-regex-character-bracket)

Better use `\w` that matches `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. In shorter form use `[\w.-]+`

---

What is the meaning for your last regex pattern?

Here `[^..]` is used for negation character set. If you uses it outside the `^[...]` then it represents the start of the line/string.

```
[^A-Za-z0-9.-_]          any character except: 
                         'A' to 'Z', 
                         'a' to 'z', 
                         '0' to '9',
                         '.' to '_'
```

Comment: [\w.-]+ this looks nice, trying it out.

Comment: I don't think so that there will be any significant performance improvement. Read [Regex Performance Optimization Tips and Tricks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252194/regex-performance-optimization-tips-and-tricks)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. `.-_` inside `[]` will match char from 46-95 in char table. I was having the same error in my regex. Put `-` at the end fixed the issue. I believe escape it with `\-` will also work.

Answer (score 1):

Just put `-` at the last in character class and add `+` after the char class to match one or more characters.

```
$text = 'username';

if (preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9._-]+$/' , $text)) {
   echo 'true';   
} else {
   echo 'false';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

function should be like this

```
function isValidUsername($str) {
    return preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9._-]+$/", $str);
}
```

Comment: i think the ^ should be after /

Comment: and - inside [] should be at the end.

Comment: it returns true if the input is an empty string.

Comment: @AvinashRaj so whats the way to get over it ?

Comment: he edited the answer now. `*` means zero or more characters, so it return true if there is no character in the input but `+` means one or more.